# How to check if my AngularJS controller is located inside a form

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-include

I have a controller that I reuse in two different places, but I want the controller to be able to distinguish wether it is used in a page that edits the data or a page that just displays the data. The difference here is that on one page the controller is located inside an `<... ng-form="someForm">` tag.

(Actually, it is a partial html file that gets included; the controller is inside that partial)

Is it possible to detect whether a controller is located inside a form? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I could create a directive that optionally requires `form` (not `ng-form`) and that you can check whether it is present or not in the link function.

```
someAngularModule
    .directive('formAware', [function(){
        return {
            require: '^?form',
            template: ' <div>{{isPartOfForm ? "Inside the form" : "Outside of the form"}}</div>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
                scope.isPartOfForm = (formCtrl !== null);
            }
        }
    }]);
```

The directive can be placed inside an ng-form (displaying the text "Inside the form"):

```
<div ng-form="myForm">
    <div form-aware></div>
<div>
```

or without an ng-form (displaying the text "Outside of the form"):

```
<div>
    <div form-aware></div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any shortcut way to fulfill your requirement, but one thing you can do is to define a variable in $rootScope to track controller's behavior. Each time a view loads with a controller it calls its define function in the javascript file.

So the idea is, in the $rootScope you'll define a flag whether your required controller is loaded or not. Then you can check the flag to know whether it has loaded or not. Also you can use $watch on the flag to get a notification when it was loaded. Let me know if any part is unclear.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I don't want to check if the controller is loaded or not. I know it is loaded, but I want to know if it is inside a form or not.  
Anyway, I would rather not mess with $rootScope. I'm looking for a solution that keeps the logic contained within the controller itself.

Comment: You can use a directive and then search for your controller name inside that directive's inner html. That way all your logic will keep as it is.